# SSIS : Read Excel File too lines

Tags: excel, ssis

I work on SSIS project (Visual studio 2012)
A browser send me an excel file with articles.
Informations begin in A2, until column G.
Then I use 
`SELECT * FROM [ProduitsFamilles$A2:G]`
My problem is, I saw in this file last line is 16143 (under empty cell)
And when I run it, It gives 16382 lines ... then 200 lines empty crush import in database cause primary key can't be empty.
I think it's because before send this file, browser delete old unless row.

Using "conditional Split" give good responce but I Want know If I can break directly empty row, like using where clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS will handle excel files and stop at the empty row automatically if you choose a table instead of a sql statement. I believe you could also select specific columns in the Select clause of an sql statement instead of defining your range in the From clause. SSIS generally assumes there is a header row, though you can also specify this.

There is another possible issue, which is that cells can be active and empty in Excel instead of inactive. To test this, press ctrl and the down arrow at the top of a full column in your sheet. It should stop at the last cell with data in it (the 16143th row in your case); if it instead goes down to the 16382th row, you'll know you have a bunch of empty but active rows that need to be taken care of before importing.

In general, it's a lot easier to use .csv files with SSIS than Excel files, which tend to have these types of formatting issues.

Comment: For CSV or Excel Files it's not my choise but this file is from Supplier. And for active but empty cell, this is the problem I try to solve ...

Comment: Try adding a where clause with something like this: WHERE [Your Primary Key Column] != ''

Comment: Of course, there are manual methods of eliminating the empty cells, and macros are available for it. But I assume you have some sort of repeating, automated process in place here.